# java swing: Query list of Jcombobox<String>

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, hashtable, jcombobox

I am just beginning with Java and Java swing.
I am working on a small meal plan program to check that the user eats all types of proteins.
It has a Jcombobox for 2 meals a day.
Is there a way to query all boxes using a for loop?

I tried this but it's not liking it:

```
public LunchMenu() {
    initComponents();
    Hashtable<String, Integer> Proteins = new Hashtable<>();
    Proteins.put("Beef", 0);
    Proteins.put("Chicken", 0);
    Proteins.put("Fish", 0);
    Proteins.put("Pork", 0);
    Proteins.put("None", 0);
}

/**
 *
 */
public void runCheck() {
    String[] comboBoxes = new String[14];
    comboBoxes = {"MonLun", "MonDin", "TueLun", "TueDin", "WesLun", "WesDin", "ThuLun", "ThuDin", "FriLun", "FriDin", "SatLun", "SatDin", "SunLun", "SunDin"};
    for (String str : comboBoxes) {
        String temp;
        temp = (String)str.getSelectedItem();
        lunch.Lunch.Proteins[temp]++;
    }
}
```

Comment: don't capitalize variable names

Comment: Your `JComboBox` looks like an String-Array.

Comment: Those are not different types of proteins, but different animals that mostly contain the same proteins.